# Delayed job vs Active job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between delayed job and active job in Ruby on Rails? Why should I use delayed job if active job is present? I have tried to find some more information but I have not been successful.

Comment: ActiveJob is a wrapper around DelayedJob. DelayedJob is the actual background job system. Resque and Sidekiq are other options for a background job system. Basically, ActiveJob lets you write your jobs in a generic way. In the future, if you wanted to switch to Resque or Sidekiq, it would be much easier because you don't have DelayedJob specific jobs. Does that make sense?

Comment: it does, thank you kindly

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ActiveJob` is very similar idea to `ActiveRecord`.

`ActiveRecord` is a wrapper. You can write code for it and then it decides how to execute it, depending which backend you're using.

`ActiveJob` is just another wrapper. In this case `DelayedJob` would be the backend that actually runs jobs. If down the road you decide to switch to something like `Resque` or `Sidekiq`, all your code should still work because translation is handled by `ActiveJob` wrapper